# Bind existing C++ application with Qt interface

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, wxwidgets, qt-designer

I have a C++ application already coded and its interface has been made with wxWidgets library. I would like to create a new interface with Qt creator.

My question is: how can I bind the C++ code with the new Qt interface?

Comment: You'll need to either rewrite your UI code or add an additional abstraction layer between your application and the target library of choice. Either way it's not going to be easy or quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have working logic, I suggest using *QtQuick* which is based on data binding. Although there's another technology named *QtWidgets* which is more classic, separation of logic/view is a bit weaker compared to *QtQuick*.

3 key concepts to get started with QtQuick with C++ binding are Q_PROPERTY / Q_INVOKABLE macros and *qmlRegisterTypes* method.

- apply Q_PROPERTY to your getter / setter which shoud interact with GUI
- apply Q_INVOKABLE to your method which should be called from GUI
- qmlRegisterTypes enables you to use your C++ type inside GUI markup files (.qml files)

It looks like below:

```
public class YourLogicClassWrapper : public QObject {
 Q_OBJECT
 Q_PROPERTY(int yourData READ yourData WRITE setYourData NOTIFY yourDataChanged)
  signals:
   yourDataChanged();
  public:
   Q_INVOKABLE void yourMethodInvokedFromGUI(int) { /* ... */ }
   // ... you need to write getter "yourData()" and setter "setYourData(int)"
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
{
  qmlRegisterTypes<YourLogicClassWrapper>("YourModule", 1, 0, "YourQmlElem");
  // ... read qml file and display window etc. all generated by QtCreator
```

Once above are done, in .qml files, your field is visible and assignable, and your method callable.

```
Import QtQuick 2.2
Import YourModule 1.0
Item {
  YourQmlElem {
    id: y
    yourData: 42
  }
  Button {
    onClicked: y.yourMethodInvokedFromGUI(1)
  }
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @nsuke! Ok, in the meantime I could study a bit more about Qt. Concerning Qt quick, is it what do you meant [http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/qml-extending.html](link)? In the documentation they said that Qt quick is more for touch devices. Mine is a desktop application. I will now try to bind a small piece of the existing code with Qt quick and Qt widgets. Another question, do you advise me to use Qt Creator or keep on using Code::Blocks where the application has been developed?

Comment: I recommend you to use QtCreator for the start. Because you need to let a certain Qt tool (namely "moc") interpret your header files before compiling. While it's automatic and nealy transpearant on QtCreator, it can be tricky on other IDEs, especially when you don't know yet how the tool is supposed to work.

Comment: And about QtQuik, you can definitely create desktop apps using it although QtWidgets may have more classic feeling. You may want to take a look at [QtQuick control](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html) which is a collection of rather traditional controls.

Comment: Great! you helped me a lot! I will do that!